# Rails: validates_acceptance_of acting crazy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

Whats wrong with this picture?

Model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, :on => :create, :accept => true, :allow_nil => false
accessor :terms_of_service
```

View:

```
<%= check_box :organisation,'terms_of_service', {:style => "margin-left:0px"}, 1, 0 %>
```

And in the DB I have organisations.terms_of_service.

Every time I get "Terms of service must be accepted"

If I use

```
<%= check_box :organisation,'terms_of_service', {:style => "margin-left:0px"}, true, false %>
```

The validation still fails.

If I turn off :accept => true, It the validation seems to pass but when I look at postgres it says false. Isn't Rails supposed to be casting this stuff?

Why don't I seem to be able to say:

Model:

```
validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, :accept => true
```

view:

```
check_box blah, blah, options, true
```

and see a true in my database?

Any ideas on whats going on?

Pertinent info: DB is Postgres and running Rails 2.1

Comment: I'm curious why you need an accessor declaration for the TOS attribute.  Doesn't rails metaprogram that into existence for database columns?

Comment: Gaaa! That fixed it. It was a leftover from some other fiddling... So obvious that I couldn't see it.
Thanks! If you want to Create an actual answer I can mark it solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `accessor` declaration for the TOS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<%= check_box :organisation,'terms_of_service', {:style => "margin-left:0px"}, '1', '0' %>
```